# AngularJS Variable inside scope or custom directive : related to ng-messages-include

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ng-messages

I am learning AngularJS, came across one scenario and not sure what is the best approach.

Below is the scenario.

The html pages are running on a server https://example.com/com/server/ and can have appended url like `/forms/resource/error.html or forms/src/main/abc.js`

When I try to include like the below it gives me `404 error` because it does not go to the exact path

```
<div ng-messages-include="error.html"></div>
```

It tries to find the html in below location obviously and gives error, can I give this path relative? tried few options did not work like giving in single quote 
https://example.com/com/server/error.html

The actual path should be https://example.com/com/server/form/resources/error.html

I know that I can give the path like

```
<div ng-messages-include="form/resources/error.html"> </div>
```

but assume the path is relatively long and would make the html look ugly if I need to add it at around 50 places.

**Suggestions on below approach**

- Create a custom directive `errorMessage` and then add as `<error-message><error-message>` and return the error-message html template, in the directive I can give the long path to the actual html template
- Or create a variable in the $scope object,say location and then set the complete string there, use that like the below
  `<div ng-messages-include='{{location}}/error.html'></div> //not sure of the syntax`

Comment: directive would look more elegant, but would leave for the seniors to discuss and elaborate the technicality

Answer (score 0):

If the path "should be https://example.com/com/server/form/resources/error.html" then write it as cuch inyour source code. The absolute path will always be correct, why not use it?

Now if you are worried about repetition, you could indeed write a custom directive.

One other option would be to have a "local" variable, a scope property like `errorTemplateURL`:

```
$scope.errorTemplateURL= 'https://example.com/com/server/form/resources/error.html';
```

Which you would then use as:

```
<div ng-messages-include="{{errorTemplateURL}}"></div>
```

But if you need to share that variable across controllers, you should create a service and inject it in any controller that needs it.

**NOTE: it is [`ng-messages-include`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages) not `ng-message-include`.**

Comment: `https://example.com/com/server/form/resources/error.html` Should be but not always, suppose we have some version of form which keeps getting bumped up like `https://example.com/com/server/form/{version can be 21>next bumped to 22> 23 and so on }/resources/error.html` . I don't need to share across the controllers but if I have to, won't it be good if i define it as a custom directive?

Comment: Also the approach suggested by you is in my mind, but is there any advantage of one over another? 1 case I believe could be when multiple controller, simply use custom directive.

Comment: like any issue at the loading time? efficiency or order of load.

Comment: If you are concerned about performance then write the messages locally in your controller instead of loading them remotely.

Comment: About creating a directive, I personnally wouldn't because [ngMessages](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages) is already flexible enough.

Comment: In the directive `templateUrl` I can give variable version number coming from config like this ${version} in the `https://example.com/com/server/form/${version}/resources/error.html `. While when i try to set the location variable in scope object, it is not getting the value of version, i tried this as well `var v=${version}`

Comment: `${version}` of config is only available in template so what i did is divided the url into two variable and then in `ng-messages-include='a/${version}/b'`